# pytest fixture autocomplete in PyCharm not working

Tags: pycharm, pytest

When using a pytest fixture as an input argument to a test function, PyCharm marks it because it "shadows the name 'fixture' from outer scope". It does not seem to understand how pytest's fixtures work and that this is intended. A side effect is that when entering the parameters to the function, there is no autocomplete for the fixture name.

Is there a way to fix this annoyance?

Comment: The only way I have been able to add the autocomplete back in is to follow type hinting annotation syntax rules as defined here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in PyCharm (already [reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25389)). Hope they'll fix it one day.

Comment: They suggest [disabling the inspection as a workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25389#comment=27-2343258) for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pytest [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10922-py-test-support) for pycharm. It will not only remove the red underline but also open the declaration of the fixture. It also allows you to autocomplete the fixture.

Code of the plugin: https://github.com/yuriikarabas/py.test-pycharm-plugin